# Meaning of って意味 in this context

Tags: meaning, expressions

In the sentence

> 俺は人にモノを教えるのは得意じゃない。人には向き不向きがあるだろ？
> 正直、勉強を教える**って意味**じゃ俺なんかより、堀北や櫛田のほうが向いている
>
> I'm not a good teacher.People have different strengths and weaknesses, right ?
> To be honest, Horikita and Kushida were better teachers than I was.

I know that って is for という, and that 意味 has a sense of "meaning" but I cannot figure out in the sentence

Comment: was something said to the speaker before this? I feel like they might be referring to dialogue before this.

Comment: I have updated the question as you suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here Japanese actually matches English usage quite closely: "teaching 勉強" is simply only one possible *sense*/*meaning* of all the kinds of teaching that "teaching モノ" (i.e., teaching in general) could conceivably entail.

> 正直、勉強を教える**って意味じゃ**俺なんかより、堀北や櫛田のほうが向いている

"To be honest, [when it comes to teaching] **in the sense of** teaching academic subjects, Horikita and Kushida are more suitable than I am."